# SqlConnection.Open succeeds when DB drive is physically disconnected

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I want to raise an exception when the the database becomes unavailable (ie. due to physically disconnecting the hard disk). I expected connection.Open() to fail in this situation, but it is successful - probably due to caching. The issue is that when the software tries to write to the DB later, it fails at that point.

My question: What is the best way to detect when the database has become unavailable?

I am using SQL Local DB, C#, .net 4.0

Comment: I think you are correct about caching (or connection pooling) fooling you.   Probably the simplest, most reliable method is to try reading one column of one row from one table.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the configuration it does not actually hit any table on an Open.
Do a simple select top 1 on a table.

If the drive with the Master database is out then Open will probably fail.

Even in SSMS you typically see the database name even if the drive with all the tables is out.